# Overcoming Memory Limitations to Visualize Large Matrices: A ggplot2 Heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, heatmap

I have a sizable matrix named parameter_tot that I aim to visualize as a heatmap in R with ggplot2. However, I'm encountering an issue due to the matrix's size, resulting in the error: "Error cannot allocate vector of size ...". Is there a workaround for this problem, or are there alternative approaches to successfully plotting the matrix given its size?

```
parameter_tot <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100000 * 10000), ncol = 100000))

colnames(parameter_tot) <- 1:ncol(parameter_tot)

parameter_tot$row <- 1:nrow(parameter_tot)

parameters_df_long <- gather(parameter_tot, key = "column", value = "value", -row)

parameters_df_long$value_log <- log1p(parameters_df_long$value)

heatmap_enet <- ggplot(parameters_df_long, aes(x = column, y = row, fill = value_log)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red", na.value = "black") +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(title = "Heatmap of Parameter Estimation Values (Log)", x = "Columns", y = "Rows")

ggsave("heatmap_enet.png", plot = heatmap_enet, width = 12, height = 8, device = "png")
```

Comment: What about `ggplot2::geom_raster()`?

Comment: I think a solution to consider is downsampling your raster to a more manageable size.
For a matrix that size, probably nobody is going to look at your visualisation at the individual-cell level detail anyway.

Comment: How are you intending to display this? To show a matrix of that size as a heatmap where individual cells are discernible to the naked eye would require a display that is more than 30 metres wide.